# Setting up raspberry pi for bluetooth low energy (bluez, bluepy)

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

I am trying to set up a brand-new Raspberry Pi for bluetooth communication using bluez and bluepy tools. This Raspberry Pi is brand-new and running NOOBS. My terminal history is the following (these are the instructions given at http://www.elinux.org/RPi_Bluetooth_LE):

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev libudev-dev libusb-dev make
mkdir -p work/bluez
cd work/bluez
ls
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.32.tar.xz
tar xvf bluez-5.32.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.32/
ls
./configure --disable-systemd
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

I also did the procedure to install bluepy, by simply cloning the bluepy repo https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy.git and using make. After running "python btle.py :mac-address:", I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to connect to peripheral :mac-address:
```

Upon running the debugger, I am seeing that the response returned from the OS helper process is "disconnected" or "disc".

I am wondering, am I missing any packages or setup steps that would cause this problem? We have another RPi that has this setup working fine, but starting with a new RPi, I am getting issues.

Comment: Any answer would be a pure guess because you don't have enough information.  Try connecting to the device with just `gatttool` and confirm that you're able to connect properly.

Comment: Are you using pi1 or 2? What bt module are you using?